# Horizontal plot in swarmplot of seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, swarmplot

**Situation**
I have the following pandas dataset:

```
|user_id|total|is_fat|
|-------|-----|------|
|1      |100  |1     |
|2      |150  |0     |
|3      |400  |1     |
|4      |500  |1     |
|5      |10   |0     |
```

where elements of the total are integer and elements of is_fat are string.

I denote above dataset by `df`.

Then run the following code:

```py
import seaborn as sos
sns.swarmplot(x = 'total', y ='is_fat', data = df)
```

Now the graph I expected looks like:
[image]

**Problem**
However, the output graph is the following:

[image]

Why?

**Search**
If I convert '1' to 'fat' and '0' to 'not_fat',
then I get the expected graph.

Comment: Try to check if `is_fat` is categorical  before using it in the plot.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I try it and get a result what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I have simulated some data and changed `is_fat` to categorical as shown:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"total":abs(np.random.randn(100)), "is_fat": [1,0]*50})
df.is_fat = df.is_fat.astype("category")
sns.swarmplot(x = 'total', y ='is_fat', data = df)
```

This produced the graph below:
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!! I could get the expected graph.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding `orient="h"` as a parameter to my call of `swarmplot()` solved the problem ([see Seaborn docs for reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)).